# Swap two- dimensional array elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is my `FCFS` algorithm.

I have a two dimensional array called `atst` means `arrival time, service time`.

Array size is `5*5`.

The logical picture of my array is this:
[image]

First column : process name

Second column : arrival time

Third column : service time (burst time)

And the Fourth and Fifth columns will be initialize for waiting time and total time after sort array by arrival time (second column).

My problem is in sorting array by second column (arrival times) by ascending order.

My code:

```
    // Sort array by arrival times
    int[] temp = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < atst.length; i++) {
        if (atst[i][1] > atst[i + 1][1]) {     // Then swap!
            temp[i] = atst[i][1];
            atst[i][1] = atst[i + 1][1];
            atst[i + 1][1] = temp[i];
        }
    }
```

I use `temp[3]` because before of sorting other columns (fourth and fifth) are empty(zero).

But this code make `arrayOutOfBoundException` in this line: `temp[i] = atst[i][1];` .

How fix this problem?

Comment: Your logical picture is not clear :P

Comment: @Karna I explain it on picture below, The numbers in the picture is for instance.

Comment: Along with tod's answer, `int[] temp = int[3]` is limited to 3 but your array has 5 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 // Sort array by arrival times
int[] temp = new int[atst.length]; //to avoid any out of bound.
for (int i = 0; i < atst.length-1; i++) { //-1 will solve
    if (atst[i][1] > atst[i + 1][1]) {     // Then swap!
        temp[i] = atst[i][1];
        atst[i][1] = atst[i + 1][1];
        atst[i + 1][1] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

Hope this will work. you have been exceeding the array bound in `atst[i+1]` for the last value of `i`. This `-1` will solve your problem of `arrayOutOfBoundException`.

EDIT: Try this:

```
 // Sort array by arrival times
int[] temp = new int[atst.length]; //to avoid any out of bound.
for (int i = 0; i < atst.length-1; i++) { //-1 will solve
    for (int j = 0; i < 2; j++) {
        if (atst[i][j] > atst[i + 1][j]) {     // Then swap!
           temp[i] = atst[i][j];
           atst[i][j] = atst[i + 1][j];
           atst[i + 1][j] = temp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result, `arrayOutOfBoundException in this line: temp[i] = atst[i][1];`

Comment: `int[][] atst = new int[5][5];`

Comment: so you also need to make `int[] temp = new int[5];` this change.i.e., 3->5

Comment: please mention it in your question so that i can update it in the answer.

Comment: It works, But as lone as `Gene` said, It just swap only the second column, Not a row. I think i need an additional `for` loop for swapping `first column` , Correct?

Comment: well that's a question other than `arrayOutOfBoundException`. Which you have not mentioned as the problem in your question. you may update your question for that too?

Answer (score 1):

Your design is broken in several ways.

First, you ought not to be using a 2d array at all. Since the columns have different meanings, an array of objects containing named fields will save you much work in the long run.

Second, what you're showing isn't close to a sort algorithm.  Even after fixing the coding problems, a single pass over an array is not sufficient to sort it.  Look at `Arrays.sort()`.

Third, your code *must* be broken by even cursory inspection.  The variable `i` iterates from `0` to `atst.length - 1`. Yet you've allocated `temp` to have only 3 positions.  Unless `atst.length` is certain to be no more than 3, you'll run off the end of `temp` with a range error.

Fourth, you want to sort rows.  The code it looks like you're trying to write will swap only the second column of each row.  The rest of the array will remain as-is.  I don't think that's what you want.

Take a step back. Think. Throw this code away.  Try again.